# Javascript setTimeout give another timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a trouble with setTimeout function in javascript, my purpose is to give timeout for each insert statement, after reach given maxrecord, it will pause for 2 hours, then continue the insert statement.

Right now im only make a work for first condition wich is given delay for each insert. But i dont know how to give 2 hour delay before continue to insert.

my code like this,

```
var ids = $("#listId").val().split('\n');

           var index = 1;
           for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
               (function(i){
                   setTimeout(function(){
                       if (index <= interval) {
                           console.log("INDEX : " + index + " INTERVAL : " + interval);
                       } else {
                           console.log("SHOULD BREAK FOR 2 HOURS (NOTHING TODO HERE, JUST DELAY) THEN CONTINUE FROM LAST IDS");
                       }
                       index++;
                   }, 1000 * i);
               }(i));
           }
```

as you can see, i need to give 2 hour's delay after index <= interval and then continue again with last i.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: 2hours? Like... real-time 2 hours or the visitor should actually keep the page alive for more than two hours?

Comment: yes @RokoC.Buljan, i make this apps for my friend, for individual purpose, my friend need to give delay for each insert, after it reach maxinterval should break for 2 hours and then continue to insert. i think should keep the page alive.

Comment: I encourage you to implement this logic on the server side rather than client side.

Comment: yes @bhspencer, i was think about that too. but it will take time to configure webapp rather than just plain html. appreciate your help..

Answer (score 1):

You are setting all of your timeouts at once, at the start, with predefined durations.

You cannot (easily) go on to modify how those times are set based on an arbitrary condition (this 2 hour delay you speak of)

Instead, you should do something like:

```
function nextRow() {
    // handle a single row
    i++;
    if( i < ids.length) setTimeout(nextRow,delay);
        // where delay is either 1000 or 7200000 as needed
}
nextRow(); // start the loop
```

Comment: thank you for help @Niet, but how about second condition where if i has reach maxInterval given, it should break for two hours and then continue from last ids inserted. for delay 2 hours, it not inserted anything, just timeout.